# Empty lines added when doing StreamReader in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to upload a local `txt` to an FTP with the following code:

```
private void CreateFile(string fileName, string userName, string password, String path)
        {
            String ftp_address = "ftp://xxxx.com/";
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp_address + fileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
            }

        }
```

But when I check the file in the FTP server per each line, it has an empty line... something like:

```
line number 1

line number 2

line number 3
```

But when I check the local file it's ok, it doesn't have the empty line after the line with the content.

The file is a simple `txt` with text separated with ;

Comment: Is there any reason you're interpreting the bytes on disk as text and then converting them back to bytes? I'd expect that if you use `File.ReadAllBytes` instead, and *also* set `request.UseBinary` to true, you should be fine.

Comment: Could it be because of the line ending characters? Some operating systems use `\n` and some use `\r\n`. Just an idea that you may check by debugging.

Comment: FtpWebRequest.UseBinary matters.  When false, the default, then you run the risk that a unixy FTP server tries to translate line endings of \r\n to \n\n.  Or whatever file viewer you used.

Comment: @HansPassant this was the issue... I have to use 'UseBinary = false' to get the right result. Could you response as an answer so I can chech it?

Comment: I can't make sense of the comment, please post the solution yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through a StreamReader and UTF8 encoding for nothing, skip that step.
It probably is converting Linux line endings to Windows or vice versa.

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: I removed the Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes section for your line, but the result is the same.